# Moving div horizontally into screen with translateX & jquery's addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

Say I have a div which I want to move into the website, as soon as this is loaded. For this I would like to use CSS3 & Jquery.

I have the following html

```
<div class="headline-box">
</div>
```

With the following CSS (SASS):

```
.headline-box {
 //some other stuff here

transition: transform 600ms ease;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);

  .visible {
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

and in jquery i do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 setTimeout(function() {
    $('.headline-box').addClass('visible');
 }, 1000);

});
```

A few more things:

- the `.visible class` is injected into the HTML after 1 sec, so this works fine
- when I replace the `.visible` for a `&:hover` (just to test) and then hover the element, the transition works fine. It is only when I replace it with `.visible` in order to add the class with jquery that it does not work

Comment: Have you tried with the amp character  `&.visible `? ... I did and it works fine

Comment: Let me know if it worked ... and if, either delete the question (or close it) as a simple _typo_ error